# NSURLConnection failed without error

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsurlconnection

i really need help to create a successful post request.

I'm trying to send user info to server by using `NSURLConnection` and i followed [this tutorial**](https://panditpakhurde.wordpress.com/2009/04/16/posting-data-to-url-in-objective-c/)

My problem is the post request seems not failed but nothing is requested to server. Here is my code:

```
-(void)sendMyRequest
{
    NSString *myJSONString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myJSONData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    
    NSData *postData = [myJSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
    
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:signupBaseURLString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    
    if(conn)
        NSLog(@"connection successful"); //it is what is printed
    else
        NSLog(@"connection failed");
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"data received"); //it is what is printed
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"connection failed with error %@", error);
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"connection did finish loading"); //it is what is printed
}
```

According to `NSLog` output 'conn' is successful, `(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data` and `(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection` delegate methods are called, error delegate method is not called. That is why i do not know what the error is or whether there is any error and if not, why my request is not delivered. Can you please help me, what i'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

** There is a line of code in [the tutorial](https://panditpakhurde.wordpress.com/2009/04/16/posting-data-to-url-in-objective-c/) that i've not used: `[request setValue:@”application/x-www-form-urlencoded” forHTTPHeaderField:@”Current-Type”];` I did not use because i did not understand `setValue` parameter "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". It may be needful, if you can enlighten me what this is about, i'd really appreciate.

**Update** I converted `NSData` object in `didReceiveData` like that `NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];` When i print it my output is really weird with that intro "Apache Tomcat/7.0.62 - Error report H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-s‌​ize:22px;}...". However at the end of the output it says **The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method** but i'm sure server expects string and i try to post in string format but setHTTPBody method force me to send NSData, so what i'm doing is to convert myJSONString to NSData then send it. Problem may be caused here but i do not know what else to do. I couldn't find a way to send directly NSString. How can i post directly NSString type?

Comment: What about appending all the data together (received in `connection: didReceiveData:`) and print it in `connectionDidFinishLoading:`? Your server may answer a special response in case of error

Comment: Let me try this, i'll tell what result is.

Comment: I kept `NSData` object in `didReceiveData`, then in `connectionDidFinishLoading:` when i try to convert it to JSON format i get the error of **Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0."** but i do not know whether this helps.

Comment: Convert it to `NSString`, not JSON. Your answer may not be JSON (as it doesn't seems to be)

Comment: I had similar issue, and the problem was about server side. Check your server may be it does not handle the data that you sent.

Comment: I converted like that `NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];` When i print it my output is really weird with that intro "<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.62 - Error report</title><style><!-H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;}...". However at the end of the output it says **The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method** but i'm sure server expects string and i post in string format.

Comment: As i said i use string format because I know server expects JSON 'string' but `setHTTPBody` method force me to send NSData, so what i'm doing is to convert myJSONString to NSData then send it. Problem may be caused here but i do not know what else to do. I couldn't find a way to send directly NSString.

Comment: @grhnkdlk what do you mean by saying server may not handling data i've sent? Shouldn't i be supposed to send the data in the format that server expects?

Comment: I'm saying that problem  may not be on your code, may be on your server side. Check logs what's happening on your service, when you make request

Comment: Thanks. I'm not in charge of server side but as server guy says nothing happens at server side no log, no warning,etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad you figured out what was wrong with your data format.  That said, there's still a related problem with the code that you should probably fix.

With NSURLConnection and NSURLSession, server-side errors are not necessarily reported as errors.  The connection is succeeding because the server is, in fact, returning data, just not the data you were expecting.

To detect these sorts of server-side errors, you should implement connection:didReceiveResponse: and check the HTTP status code returned by the server.  If it isn't 200 (OK), handle it in whatever way makes sense for your particular application.  This is also your only opportunity to obtain various pieces of info that you might need later, such as HTTP headers values, which are stored in the NSHTTPURLResponse object.

(Of course, if the data you get back isn't in the expected format, handle that as an error, too, even if you got a 200 status code and the request seemed to succeed.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put some code in info.plist file.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

You can get more information form below link.

http://iosdevtips.co/post/121756573323/ios-9-xcode-7-http-connect-server-error

Answer (score 0):

Adding below lines in `sendMyRequest` method solved my problem.

```
[request setValue:@”application/x-www-form-urlencoded” forHTTPHeaderField:@”Current-Type”];
[request setValue:@”application/json” forHTTPHeaderField:@”Content-Type”];
[request setValue:@”application/json” forHTTPHeaderField:@”Accept”];
```